# PHP imagettftext center text left,right,top,bottom

Tags: php, gd, imagettftext

I have created some function to generate an avatar for my users, but some letters can't set in the center.

Here is how the images looks

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YK89.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IxFQ.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP2U2.png]

And code

```
    $font = 'arial.ttf';
    $font_size = '120';
    $angle = '0';
    $text = 'M';

    // Create the image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(200,240);

    $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, $bgColor[0],$bgColor[1],$bgColor[2]);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255,255);

    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 240, $bg);

    $text_box = imagettfbbox($font_size,$angle,$font,$text);
    $text_width = $text_box[2]-$text_box[0];
    $text_height = $text_box[7]-$text_box[1];

    $x = 100 - ($text_width/2);
    $y = 120 - ($text_height/2);

    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, $font_size, $angle, $x, $y, $white, $font, $text);
```

Not sure where the problem is, maybe that `imagettfbbox` does not read font size properly?

Also, I was trying  to find a solution on StackOverflow but can't

Comment: You can use a monospace font which will improve your problem.

Comment: Not really, i was try some monospaced fonts

Comment: Can you try the following?
$x = ($100/2) - ($text_width/2);
$y = (120/2) - ($text_height/2);